# $ f(x)=\begin{cases}\sin x& \text{if $x$ is rational}\\{\cos x} &\text{if $x$ is irrational}\end{cases} $, finding continuous point

Tags: calculus, continuity

**Problem:** Where the following function continuous?$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\sin {x}& \text{$x\in\mathbb Q$}\\ \cos{x} &\text{$x\notin\mathbb Q$}\end{cases} $$

We can predict that $f$ might be continuous at $x={\pi\over4}+k\pi$ where $k\in\mathbb Z$, and otherwise discontinuous. I want to prove this using $\epsilon-\delta$ argument. For example, at $x={\pi\over4}$, for example, it was difficult to express suitable $\delta$ to derive that $|f(x)-{1\over\sqrt2}|\lt\epsilon$.

I learned that it can be proven by using dirichlet $d(x)$, which is $$d(x)=\begin{cases}0&x\in\mathbb Q \\1&x\notin\mathbb Q\end{cases}$$
By setting $f(x):=\sin{x}+d(x)(\cos{x}-\sin{x})$ and $h(x):=\cos{x}-\sin{x}$. We are firstly going to focus on $d(x)h(x)$.

If $h(a)=0$, then $d(x)h(x)$ is continuous at $a$ since $$\forall\epsilon\gt0, \exists\delta>0 s.t 0\lt|x-a|\lt\delta\implies |d(x)h(x)-d(a)h(a)|=|d(x)h(x)|\le|h(x)|\lt\epsilon$$
Note that $h$ is continuous.

If $h(a)\ne0$, we claim that $d(x)h(x)$ is discontinuous.
Suppose $d(x)h(x)$ is continuous, since $h(x)$ is also continuous, so is $d(x)=\frac{d(x)h(x)}{2}$. However, we can easily prove that $d(x)$ is discontinuous at every point, so it's contradiction" $d(x)h(x)$ is discontinuous.

When $h(x)=0$, $x={\pi\over4}+n\pi$; at such $x$, $f$ is continuous as we proved.

But, I do want to know the solution that does not use *without* dirichlet function. I tried it, but it was difficult to set up $delta$. Is there an exact way to solve this?

Thanks very much.

**NOTE** I have to prove not only continuity at $x={\pi\over4}+k\pi$ but also discontinuity at other points!

**NOTE** I cannot use limits of sequence in the test, so I really want the solution with epsilon-delta arguements.

Comment: It's easy to set up $\delta$! You have $\delta_{\sin}$ from the continuity of $\sin$, and $\delta_{\cos}$ from the continuity of $\cos$; now just take their minimum.

Answer (score 2):

$f$ is continuous at a point $p$ if and only if for every convergent sequence $p_n$ such that $\lim p_n = p$, $\lim f(p_n) = f(p)$. Now we can approach a point $p$ by both rational sequences and irrational sequences. So given $p$, there is a rational sequence $p'_n$ and an irrational sequence $p_n''$ both of which converge to $p$. So if $f$ is continuous $p$, then $f(p) = \lim f(p_n') = \lim f(p_n'')$. But by definition this is the same as $f(p) = \lim \sin(p'_n) = \lim \cos(p_n'')$. But since $\cos$ and $\sin$ are continuous functions, this boils down to $f(p) = \cos(p) = \sin(p)$. So $f$ is continuous at those points $p$ where $\cos(p) = \sin(p)$.

Comment: How about discontinuity at other points?

Comment: @ToBY: This argument works in both directions.

Comment: Ah, I understand it. That's a good approach, and I learned a lot. But sadly, I cannot use the sequence approach in this mid test, so I need epsilon-delta arguments. Could you add some epsilon-delta arguments: esp. in the case of discontinuity.

Answer (score 1):

Attempt

MVT:

$|\sin x-\sin π/4| \lt |x-π/4|$;

$|\cos x - \cos π/4| \lt |x-π/4|$.

Thus

$|f(x)-1/√2| \lt |x-π/4|$;

Let $\epsilon >0$ be given.

Choose $\delta=\epsilon$.

Then

$|x-π/4| \lt \delta$ implies

$|f(x)-1/√2| \lt |x-π/4| \lt \delta =\epsilon$.

Used:

$\dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=f'(t)$, where $t \in (a,x)$ for $x >a$, and $t \in (x,a)$ for $x <a$.

Comment: How about discontinuity at other points?

Comment: ToBy. By now you may have gotten a few ideas. Assume $x$, rational. Choose an irrational sequence $x_n$ converging to $x$. $f(x)=\sin x$. $\lim_{n} x_n = \cos x \not =\sin x$, since $\lim_{n} \cos x_n=\cos x$. Not continuos. Your thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Sin x and cos x are continuous everywhere.

If you use any rule where f(x) is either sin x or cos x, then f is continuous in every point where sin x = cos x. Which is at (n + 1/4)pi.

Comment: I have to write this ideas precisely, sir.

Answer (score 0):

To find the $\delta$ you better use the fact that

$$|\sin(x+\pi/4) - \cos(x+\pi/4)| = 2 \sqrt{2}|\sin(x)|$$

And note that for $|x|<\pi/4$

$$\|f(x+\pi/4)-\sqrt{2}\| \le \max \{ |\sin(x+\pi/4)-\sqrt{2}|, |\cos(x+\pi/4)- \sqrt{2}|\} \le$$
$$\le |\sin(x+\pi/4) - \cos(x+\pi/4)| = 2 \sqrt{2}|\sin(x)| < 2\sqrt{2}|x|$$

So if you take $\delta = \varepsilon 2^{-3/2}$ it should be fine.

Comment: How about discontinuity at other points?

Comment: Oh sure. Let $y$ be such that $\sin(y) \neq cos(y)$, set $A:=|\sin(y)-\cos(y)|>0$, then for any given $\delta>0$ you can find values $x$, both in $\mathbb{Q}=Q$ and $\mathbb{R}\setminus Q$ such that s.t. $|x-y|<\delta$ and $|\sin(x)-\sin(y)|<A/2$ and $|\cos(x)-cos(y)|<A/2$. Therefore: if, say, $y \in Q$, you can find an $x\notin Q$ with $|x-y|<\delta$, and $|\cos(x)-\cos(y)|<A/2$ then $|f(y)- \cos(x)| = |\sin(y)-\cos(x)| \ge |\sin(y)-\cos(y)| - |\cos(y)-\cos(x)| \ge A-A/2=A/2$ If instead $y \notin Q$ you can do an anlogue, just looking for an $x \in Q$ for which $|sin(x)-sin(y)|<A/2$.

Comment: Ah, I understand, sir. Can I ask one more? (Sorry) Why for $|x|<{\pi/4}, \max \{ |\sin(x+\pi/4)-\sqrt{2}|, |\cos(x+\pi/4)- \sqrt{2}|\} 
\le |\sin(x+\pi/4) - \cos(x+\pi/4)| $ holds?

Comment: It follows from the fact that if $|x|<\pi/$, then $\sqrt{2}$ always lays between  $\sin(x+\pi/4)$ and $\cos(x+\pi/4)$ so its distance from $\cos(x+\pi/4)$ or $\sin(x+\pi/4)$ is smaller than the distance between $\sin(x+\pi/4)$ and $\cos(x+\pi/4)$.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x) = f((x-\frac {\pi}{4}) + \frac \pi4) = \begin{cases} \frac {\sqrt 2}2 \sin (x-\frac \pi4)+\frac {\sqrt 2}2 \cos (x-\frac \pi4) & x\in \mathbb Q\\\frac {\sqrt 2}2 \cos (x-\frac \pi4)-\frac {\sqrt 2}2 \sin (x-\frac \pi4) & x\notin \mathbb Q\end{cases}$

Note that $|\sin x| \le x$

$|x-\frac {\pi}4|<\delta \implies \frac {\sqrt 2}{2}\cos x - \frac {\sqrt 2}{2}\delta \le f(x) \le \frac {\sqrt 2}{2}\cos x + \frac {\sqrt 2}{2}\delta$

Comment: I have a question, sir. When we divided into two cases to use epsilon-delta arguments, my teachers always gave me zero point. So, I'm not sure that dividing into ratiobal case and irrational case is a precise solution.

Comment: I am not dividing into two cases for the $\delta - \epsilon$ argument.  In both cases the last line holds